# Android Studio 3.3: can't see layout preview

Tags: android, android-studio

I can't see the layout preview in *Android Studio* 3.1.3.

[image]

Comment: On the bottom, change from design to text and share the screenshot. This way we can know what is going on.

Comment: view->tool windows->preview show the preview window on design

Comment: Please paste your project build.gradle.

Comment: Try changing the Theme from the top of the preview. If this didn’t help, perhops you’re using versions of AppCompat library which has issue. Update to 28.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I want to know your `compileSdkVersion`? If `compileSdkVersion` is equal to 28, reduced it to 27. And then sync it. Perhaps, It will resolve your problem.
It solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see the same issue with *Android Studio* 3.1.3.

One fix that worked for me was to uninstall and reinstall the tool.